# How to execute a dos command on multiple active directory computers?

Tags: active-directory, uninstall, system-center, agent

I need to uninstall the system center agent applications from all the computers in an active directory.   Unfortunately I do not have the system center install/machine to do this, so I am hoping I can push a dos command out to all the machines in the AD - how can I do this?   - I found this command works if I execute it locally from the command prompt:

msiexec /x {25097770-2B1F-49F6-AB9D-1C708B96262A} /qn /norestart

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put it into a startup script and link that GPO so that all computers will process it.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing - a GPO login script in AD.  However the psexec method looks like a nice method / tool too!

Comment: The psexec method needs the machines to be on. This guarantees that it's applied to all machines that you want it to be applied to.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add another tool, PDQ deploy (free) can also be used for things like this if you prefer a GUI interface. It'll also give you a status on which machines it has applied to as well, which can be handy.

[PDQ Deploy](http://www.adminarsenal.com/pdq-deploy/main/)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a for loop and then use psexec. For example like this:

```
for /f %%a in (computers.txt) do (
echo Processing command >> Logfile.txt
psexec /accepteula \\%%a -e -w C:\ %Windir%\System32\msiexec.exe /x {25097770-2B1F-49F6-AB9D-1C708B96262A} /qn /norestart >> Logfile.txt
echo Done processing command >> Logfile.txt
)
```

Some explantion specify in computers.txt the computers to process and Logfile.txt is a log file created.